# Agora RTM Web SDK throwing error after build using Angular Server Side Rendering (SSR)

Tags: angular, agora.io

Happening after Angular 8 SSR build using webpack, agora rtm installed using npm. It is an agora rtm code bug.

Agora RTM web SDK 1.2.1 minified code has issues,

```
line7: var _global=createCommonjsModule(function(e){var t=e.exports="undefined"!=typeof ....
```

this variable is not taking RegExp from window,
In  later part `$RegExp = _global.RegExp` assigned, `$RegExp.prototype` call happening after that throwing error 'prototype' of undefined.

Comment: Were you able to fix this bug?

Comment: I could not fix it @vineethsrini.